# Way to stop java.util.concurrent.Executor task

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to know is there any way to stop java.util.concurrent.Executor task in elegant manner or we should use java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService which is one layer above java.util.concurrent.Executor (java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService has API for shutdown) ?

```
package com.example;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ExecutorTaskExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        ThreadTask task = new ThreadTask();
        task.setTaskName("task_"+i);
        executor.execute(task);
    }
    System.out.println("Program Completed");
}

}

class ThreadTask implements Runnable{
private String taskName;

@Override
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Task: "+this.getTaskName()+"processed by "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getTaskName() {
    return taskName;
}

public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.concurrent.Executor` does not have any specific method to terminate task.

You can use `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` for this purpose.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    ThreadTask task = new ThreadTask();
    task.setTaskName("task_"+i);
    executor.execute(task);

    if (some condition) {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

But for executor.shutdown() method doc states that

`Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.`

**Update:**

I have tried below code. I think this is what you were looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    List<Future<?>> list = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ThreadTask task = new ThreadTask();
        task.setTaskName("task_" + i);
        Future<?> future = executor.submit(task);
        list.add(future);
    }
    for (Future<?> f : list) {
        if (!f.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("Running thread terminating");
            f.cancel(true);
        }
    }
    for (Future<?> f : list) {
        if (f.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("Running thread terminated");
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Program Completed");
}
```

Comment: It seems ExecutorService interface added above Executor interface to handle Thread life cycle management.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "elegant" way to externally stop a Thread in Java.

You need to have your code check for "shouldStop" flags from time to time and exit by itself.

This is no different, no matter what API you use (short of one heavily deprecated Thread method I will not link to).

[ExecutorService#shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) will not do anything to currently running tasks. It will even continue to start queued tasks if there still are any. It will just stop accepting new ones.

[ExecutorService#shutdownNow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) will be a bit more aggressive in that it sends `interrupt()` to running Threads (but it is still up to the running application code how to deal with that).

FWIW, your Thread#sleep would be interrupted that way.

Comment: Can you please review my updated code. Can it be an accepted way to externally stop a Thread in java?